# Looking for a new laptop

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a new laptop, better than the one I have got right now.

Currently, I have got an Acer with an AMD E2-3800 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics 1.30GHz and 8 GB RAM.

I have been looking and I have found a HP 250 G6, with an i3-6006U, Intel HD 520 and 8 GB RAM.

I want to be sure the difference between them with be enough.

Comment: To be honest the difference between those laptops isn't going to be great. You won't be playing games at highest setting on that new laptop. It's more than enough for web browsing and word processing, however.

Comment: I would take a look at the Dell Inspiron 15 5567 for very good performance. I personally have one of these, and the price to performance is very good.